# Auto Complete in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am new in ng. I want to create an autocomplete textbox which triggers an AJAX call, when changing text. But minimum length to AJAX call will be 3 characters AND when user enters 4th,5th or 6th character it does not again do AJAX call but it will sort from previous data only.
So basically, it will do AJAX call only when first 3 characters are changed(and also min 3 chars).

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think uib-typeahead is a good option. check this https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#typeahead if you can use UI-Bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Sort of a lengthy explanation, hence writing as an answer.

The function for 3 letters at least:

```
$scope.checkTitle = function(lettersTyped){
    if(lettersTyped.length > 2){
            //make API call here
          $scope.limitTitleSearch = 500;
    }else{
          $scope.limitTitleSearch = 0;
    }
}
```

`HTML5` has an existing element called `<datalist>` which helps in autocompletion along with a select text box. But it does not work very well in Chrome. It does a `matches` instead of `contains` and hence you cannot search for "Hello" in "Hi! Hello there" and receive a positive response on Chrome. Works on FF!

Hence, I recommend using `angular-ui`'s `ui-select`.
Sample [Plnkr](http://embed.plnkr.co/jBJkDb) by mkearl. Hope this helps!.